# Text appearing before command prompt

Tags: c, gcc

I recently began learning C programming language. I tried executing the Hello World program, but I've encountered a strange issue. I tried copying the text exactly how it is displayed in the tutorial. I am using the vim text editor. I saved the file as hello.c. After I finish typing the code I use gcc to compile the code. This is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     printf("Hello World!/n");
     return 0;
}
```

then I compiled the code:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

then I execute the code with ./ and I got:

```
Hello World!/nusername@machinename:~$
```

Comment: If your tutorial has `"Hello World!/n"` in it instead of `"Hello World!\n"` then you should find another one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its just that the prompt is appearing after printing the output of your program and you are using `/n` instead of `\n`, so there is no new line printed along with `Hello World`